# How can I check if a value exists inside an array of objects in javaSript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**For eg.**

```
[
    {
      x:1,
      y:2
     },
     {
       x:10,
       y:20
     },
]
```

How can I check if x exists in both of the objects inside the array?

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

if x doesn't exist in even one object inside the array ---> false 
else ---->true

I have tried using the [array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method but not able to find the right logic to get the desired output.

Comment: `arr.some(o => o.property === target)`

Comment: This question has been answered before now. Search for it or soon, someone will flag this question as a duplicate

Comment: @Ele seems like OP just wants `target in o`

Comment: @VLAZ ummm, probably!

Comment: @NipunJain No, it does not, I 've read it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

You could check the objects with [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and the wanted property and take [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for checking all elements of the array.

```js
var array = [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 10, y: 20 }],
    result = array.every(o => o.hasOwnProperty('x'));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Alternative `'x' in o`. Just in case it's coming from a prototype.

Comment: @VLAZ, unlikely in an object literal ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator `in` for checking if a property exists in the object, this along with the function `every`.

```js
let arr = [{x:1,y:2},{x:10,y:20}];
console.log(arr.every((o) => "x" in o))
console.log(arr.every((o) => "z" in o))
```